# Hide non-continuous columns based on the value of another cell (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to hide columns based on the value (Country Name) of a certain cell.

I am able to hide column based on one country but I am unable to get all three of my countries to work at the same time.
Currently my code looks likes this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Selectionchange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B31").Value = England Then
        Range("E:F,H:I,K:L:N:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Range("E:F,H:I,K:L,N:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
        If Range("B31").Value = Wales Then
     Range("D:D,F:G,I:J:L:M,N:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Range("D:D,F:G,I:J:L:M,N:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
        If Range("B31").Value = Scotland Then
     Range("D:E,G:H,J:K:M:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Range("D:E,G:H,J:K:M:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And when the text is entered in the desired cell all columns are hidden and I would only like the columns not relevant to the country. Is it possible to have only the relevant columns hide when the country is hidden with the current set up/ code I am using. Many thanks, this is my first attempt at macros so I am pretty new.

Comment: Could you kindly correct your range addresses? I mean, what are those `K:L:N:O`, `I:J:L:M`, and `J:K:M:N`? The letters seem also wrong. A better approach may be to show/hide first all relevant columns and then hide/show the columns irrelevant/relevant for a country. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66259737/edit) your post at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Show/Hide Non-Contiguous Columns

- In this case, the [`Worksheet.Change event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) will only be triggered when the value in cell `B31` is changed manually or via `VBA`. Manually also includes e.g. a [`drop-down list`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b).
- The `Worksheet_Change` procedure has to be copied to the appropriate sheet module e.g. `Sheet1`.
- The other two procedures are usually copied to a standard module e.g. `Module1` to easily be called from another worksheet. **Only one** is to be used. They show the two different approaches:

  1. all columns can be shown and the country-irrelevant columns can be hidden (your way), or
  2. all columns can be hidden and then the country-relevant columns can be shown.
- `UCase` and the countries written in UPPERCASE are used to allow case-insensitivity (`A = a`) in the worksheet cell.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Define monitored cell (range).
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Range("B31")
    
    ' Check if the value in the monitored cell has changed.
    If Not Intersect(Target, sCell) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ' Either your way...
        HideWay sCell
        ' ... or another way:
        'ShowWay sCell
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Sub HideWay(MonitoredCell As Range)
    With MonitoredCell.Worksheet
        ' Show all columns.
        .Columns("D:O").Hidden = False
        ' Hide country-irrelevant columns.
        Select Case UCase(MonitoredCell.Value)
            Case "ENGLAND"
                ' Showing columns 'D, G, J, M'
                .Range("E:F,H:I,K:L,N:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case "WALES"
                ' Showing columns 'E, H, K, N'
                .Range("D:D,F:G,I:J,L:M,O:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case "SCOTLAND"
                ' Showing columns 'F, I, L, O'
                .Range("D:E,G:H,J:K,M:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case Else
                ' Columns are already shown.
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Sub ShowWay(MonitoredCell As Range)
    With MonitoredCell.Worksheet
        ' Hide all columns.
        .Columns("D:O").Hidden = True
        ' Show country-relevant columns.
        Select Case UCase(MonitoredCell.Value)
            Case "ENGLAND"
                .Range("D:D,G:G,J:J,M:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case "WALES"
                .Range("E:E,H:H,K:K,N:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case "SCOTLAND"
                .Range("F:F,I:I,L:L,O:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case Else
                ' Show all columns.
                .Columns("D:O").Hidden = False
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, think that has sorted it

Answer (score 0):

if i undersand you right it should help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Selectionchange(ByVal Target As Range)
    dim c as range : set c = Range("B31")
    If c.Value = "England" or c.Value = "Wales" or c.Value = "Scotland" Then
        Range("E:F,H:I,K:L:N:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Range("E:F,H:I,K:L,N:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End 
If End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it didnt seem to solve the issue. Additionally, should I not need more lines of code with regards to the range as the columns I want to be hidden vary depending on which country is inputted into the cell, as does the code youve written not mean that they all have the same ranges. For example if I input England, I want all the columns that refer to Wales and Scotland to be hidden as theyre not relevant. Hope that makes a little more sense.